# How do I count individual text count from a column from all records

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, join, coalesce

I need to display count of each text occurrence on all rows  from a particular column.

See result below:

[image]
Here I have a set of Tags, I need to display count each tag as column in the name 'Total'

What I have done is:

```sql
DECLARE @tags VARCHAR(8000) 
DECLARE @tot INT
select @tags = coalesce(@tags + ',' , ' ') + Labels from addNew 
select @tot = count(@tags)
select a.Labels as Tags,@tot as Total from addNew a 
inner join addNew n
on a.Labels = n.Labels
group by a.Labels
```

The result must be:

[image]

Get the query code: [individual_count_set.sql](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/uploadfile/0af87b/10052017142210PM/SQLQuery.rar) 

Please suggest your queries to get my desired result.

Thank in Advance.

Comment: The task seems easy if you are using sql server 2016 version. Can you please add the version of your sql server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using versions other than **SQL SERVER 2016**, you need to create an **User defined function** to split these comma separated strings.

The whole answer is as follows:

```
Go

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].StringSplit
(
    @Labels varchar(8000)
)
RETURNS @RESULT TABLE(Value VARCHAR(8000))
AS
BEGIN     
 DECLARE @SeparatorPosition INT = CHARINDEX(',', @Labels ),
        @Value VARCHAR(8000), @StartPosition INT = 1

 IF @SeparatorPosition = 0  
  BEGIN
   INSERT INTO @RESULT VALUES(@Labels)
   RETURN
  END

 SET @Labels = @Labels + ','
 WHILE @SeparatorPosition > 0
  BEGIN
   SET @Value = SUBSTRING(@Labels , @StartPosition, @SeparatorPosition- @StartPosition)

   IF( @Value <> ''  ) 
    INSERT INTO @RESULT VALUES(@Value)

   SET @StartPosition = @SeparatorPosition + 1
   SET @SeparatorPosition = CHARINDEX(',', @Labels , @StartPosition)
  END    

 RETURN
END
Go
```

After creating the above function, following query should get the job done:

```
select concat(fn.Value,'(',count(fn.Value),')') as TagCount 
from addnew a
 cross apply
   STRINGSPLIT(a.Labels) as fn
 group by fn.Value
 order by TagCount;
```

[Working Example](http://rextester.com/VMZL48786)

Note: If you are using **Sql Server 2016**, then you can use in-built function `STRING_SPLIT()`.

For more info [click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)

**Solution for SQL SERVER 2016:**

```
select concat(fn.Value,'(',count(fn.Value),')') as TagCount 
    from addnew a
     cross apply
       STRING_SPLIT(a.Labels) as fn  //use in-built function, no need to create UDF
     group by fn.Value
     order by TagCount;
```

Hope it helps!