# SQL String Spilt by Comma and spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, substring

I want to spilt `data` column into 3 new columns

1. last
2. first
3. post

data have values with Spaces OR ',' Comma Se-prated.

```
data
ABC, RICK SEAN, MD
MES, AEL B, MD FACC
DAN, RK, MD
OHI, NIK, MD F
KA E SYME, PA-C
ALL MUD, SIM, MD
RINE EEMAN, FNP-C
ABC, PQR DIR
```

Required Output :

```
desc                        last        first       post

ABC, RICK SEAN, MD          ABC         RICK SEAN   MD          
MES, AEL B, MD FACC         MES         AEL B       MD FACC
DAN, RK, MD                 DAN         RK          MD
OHI, NIK, MD F              OHI         NIK         MD F
KA E SYME, PA-C             KA          E SYME      PA-C
ALL MUD, SIM, MD            ALL MUD     SIM         MD
RINE EEMAN, FNP-C           RINE        EEMAN       FNP-C
ABC, PQR DIR                ABC         PQR         DIR
```

check first row  data column  have 2 commas and last row have only one comma.

sample created here http://rextester.com/BEHUP42399

```
select left(data, charindex(',', data) -1)  from TTT
```

It tried for 'last' name Column but giving wrong o/p for 'KA E SYME' i.e. Single comma record.
if data have single comma and before comma there is only one word means after comma there are two words then result will be. Check Last Record ABVC.

```
eg. ABC, PQR DIR
```

Comment: how can someone know that E SYME and ALL MUD should not be separated? What is the reason behind that?

Comment: This answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46595896/2225030

Comment: You'll be better off doing it in your application code. SQL is not the right tool for this job

Comment: @Harshil E SYME have one comma and ALL MUD have two commas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try it using `CROSS APLLY` :

```
    SELECT N.DATA [descr],
       CASE
           WHEN N.last = ''
           THEN LTRIM(N.first)
           ELSE LTRIM(N.last)
       END last,
       CASE
           WHEN N.last = ''
           THEN SUBSTRING(LTRIM(N.post), 1, CHARINDEX(CHAR(32), LTRIM(N.post)))
           ELSE LTRIM(N.first)
       END first,
       CASE
           WHEN N.last = ''
           THEN SUBSTRING(LTRIM(N.post), (CHARINDEX(' ', LTRIM(N.post))+1), LEN(LTRIM(N.post)))
           ELSE LTRIM(N.post)
       END post
FROM
(
    SELECT D.DATA,
           CASE
               WHEN D.post IS NULL
               THEN LEFT(D.last, CHARINDEX(' ', D.last))
               ELSE D.last
           END last,
           CASE
               WHEN d.post IS NULL
               THEN SUBSTRING(D.last, (CHARINDEX(' ', D.last)+1), LEN(D.last))
               ELSE d.first
           END first,
           CASE
               WHEN D.post IS NULL
               THEN d.first
               ELSE d.post
           END post
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
               DATA,
               Split.a.value('/M[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') last,
               Split.a.value('/M[2]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') first,
               Split.a.value('/M[3]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') post
        FROM
        (
            SELECT DATA,
                   CAST('<M>'+REPLACE(DATA, ',', '</M><M>')+'</M>' AS XML) AS String
            FROM #TM
        ) A
        CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/M') Split(a)
    ) D
) N;
```

**Desired Result :**

```
desc                        last        first       post

ABC, RICK SEAN, MD          ABC         RICK SEAN   MD          
MES, AEL B, MD FACC         MES         AEL B       MD FACC
DAN, RK, MD                 DAN         RK          MD
OHI, NIK, MD F              OHI         NIK         MD F
KA E SYME, PA-C             KA          E SYME      PA-C
ALL MUD, SIM, MD            ALL MUD     SIM         MD
RINE EEMAN, FNP-C           RINE        EEMAN       FNP-C
ABC, PQR DIR                ABC         PQR         DIR
```

Note : The above result as per data provided.

Comment: Its work for 2 comma serapted string . What for single comma string.like RINE EEMAN, FNP-C

Comment: ITs Work but i have one more condition. New Condition added in Sampel data.

Answer (score 1):

you can try a query like below

Logic is that we find the number of commas and add commas for first occurring spaces when commas are less than 3
This also works when there are no commas at all in string.

```
create table staging_tbl_single_row (data varchar(max))
insert into staging_tbl_single_row values
('ABC, RICK SEAN, MD')
,('MES, AEL B, MD FACC')
,('DAN, RK, MD')
,('OHI, NIK, MD F')
,('KA E SYME, PA-C')
,('ALL MUD, SIM, MD')
,('RINE EEMAN, FNP-C'),
('ABC, PQR DIR');

; with cte as 
(
 select 
    row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as column1,
    column2=
    case
        when 
             (len(data)-len(replace(data,',',''))=2) 
        then 
             data 
        when 
             (len(data)-len(replace(data,',',''))=1) 
        then 
             case --check if space is to the left of comma
                    when 
                        charindex(' ',left(data, charindex(',',data)))<>0
                    then 
                        stuff(data,charindex(' ',data),1,',')
                    else 
                        left(data, charindex(',',data))+
                        stuff(
                            substring(data,
                                      charindex(',',data)+1,
                                      len(data)
                                     ),
                            charindex(' ',
                                      substring(
                                          data,
                                          charindex(',',data)+1,
                                          len(data)
                                          ),
                                      2)
                            ,1,',')
                    end

       when
            (len(data)-len(replace(data,',',''))=0)
        then
              stuff(
       stuff(data,charindex(' ',data),1,',')
        ,charindex(' ',stuff(data,charindex(' ',data),1,','))
       ,1,',')

    end,data
    from 
    staging_tbl_single_row
)

select 
    last=[1],first=[2],post=[3]
from 
(
    select 
        t.column1,
        split_values=SUBSTRING( t.column2, t1.N, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',',t.column2,t1.N),0)-t1.N,8000)),
        r= row_number() over( partition by column1 order by t1.N) 
    from cte t 
        join
        (
            select 
                t.column2,
                1 as N 
            from cte t  
                UNION ALL
            select 
                t.column2,
                t1.N + 1 as N
            from cte t 
                join
                (
                 select 
                    top 8000
                        row_number() over(order by (select NULL)) as N 
                 from 
                    sys.objects s1 
                        cross join 
                   sys.objects s2 
                ) t1 
            on SUBSTRING(t.column2,t1.N,1) = ','
         ) t1
          on t1.column2=t.column2
)a
pivot
( 
    max(split_values) for r in ([1],[2],[3])
   )p
```

<kbd>**[see working demo](http://rextester.com/QQQNQA79711)**</kbd>

Comment: can you check this condtion 'ABC, PQR DIR'. sry i forgot to mention

Comment: Its Work but for 1 million records it  takes to much time. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH Split_Names (data, xmlname)
AS
(
    SELECT data,

    CONVERT(XML,'<Names><name>'  
    + REPLACE(data,',', '</name><name>') + '</name></Names>') AS xmlname
      FROM TTT
)

SELECT  CASE
           WHEN s.post IS NULL
           THEN LEFT(s.last, CHARINDEX(' ', s.last)-1)
           ELSE s.last
       END last,
       CASE
           WHEN s.post IS NULL
           THEN SUBSTRING(s.last, (CHARINDEX(' ', s.last)+1), LEN(s.last))
           ELSE s.first
       END first,
       CASE
           WHEN s.post IS NULL
           THEN s.first
           ELSE s.post
       END Post FROM
(
SELECT data,      
 xmlname.value('/Names[1]/name[1]','varchar(MAX)') AS Last,    
 xmlname.value('/Names[1]/name[2]','varchar(MAX)') AS First,
 xmlname.value('/Names[1]/name[3]','varchar(MAX)') AS Post
 FROM Split_Names
)s
```

Comment: can you check this condtion 'ABC, PQR DIR'. sry i forgot to mention